# usage of new year's eve?

Tags: verbs, usage

What are the proper usage of New year's eve in the below sentence? Or, What are verbs for New Year's Eve?

For example, the scenario is like this. I have to choose to have my New year's eve with my parents or my wife's. So far the only verb I know is HAVE. Is it proper? And is there any better way to express it? Such as that I have choose one from my parents and my wife's for New year's eve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when we are talking about holidays, we say that we spend them. This is probably the most natural word to use in this situation. So, I would rewrite your example sentence like this:

> I have to make a choice with whom to **spend** New Year's Eve. Either with my parents or my wife's parents.

However, the verb **have** is absolutely fine too:

> I'm going to **have** Christmas with my wife's family this year.

As you can see, both work. The only thing to note here is that **spend** is on average a more common verb to use when talking about holidays, birthdays, Christmas, et cetera.